# Bind data from textBox to ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, bind

I have a program that bind data from 4 textBox to ListView.

XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="TestBindingData.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="324" Width="592">
    <Grid>
        <ListView Height="209" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,64,0,0" Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="546" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding STT}" Header="STT" Width="50"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HVT}" Header="Name" Width="200"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" Header="Age" Width="50"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding State}" Header="State" Width="200"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <TextBox Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="99,25,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="45" />
        <TextBox Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,25,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138" />
        <TextBox Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="294,25,0,0" Name="textBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="45" />
        <TextBox Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="345,25,0,0" Name="textBox4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" />
        <Button Content="Add" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="461,27,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow Code:

```
namespace TestBindingData
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        class person
        {
            public string STT { get; set; }
            public string HVT { get; set; }
            public string Age { get; set; }
            public string State { get; set; }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<person> people = new List<person>();
            people.Add(new person() { STT = textBox1.Text.ToString(), HVT = textBox2.Text.ToString(), Age = textBox3.Text.ToString(), State = textBox4.Text.ToString() });
            this.listView1.ItemsSource = people;
        }
    }
}
```

When I click button Add, program will add a row that contain people's information. But I can't add row 2, row 3,... after row 1!
Please help, thanks!

Comment: Why are you adding data using textboxes? If you use datagrid and bind an observable collection to it you would not need textboxes and ListView. Offcourse you can also do it with ListView alone.

Comment: As @CSharpYouDull pointed out you should bind your listview to an ObservableCollection in your viewmodel and then Command bind the button to your viewmodel where you will add the data to the existing ObservableCollection

Answer (score 0):

you should be using an observable collection as the source that way you don't need to set the items source every time. Observable collections will notify on change so the UI will respond to new additions to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this->

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            private ObservableCollection<person> _people;

            public ObservableCollection<person> people
            {
                get { return _people; }
                set { _people = value; }
            }
            public MainWindow()
            {
InitializeComponent();
                people = new ObservableCollection<person>();
            }
           public class person
            {
                public string STT { get; set; }
                public string HVT { get; set; }
                public string Age { get; set; }
                public string State { get; set; }
            }

            public void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {           
                people.Add(new person() { STT = textBox1.Text.ToString(), HVT = textBox2.Text.ToString(), Age = textBox3.Text.ToString(), State = textBox4.Text.ToString() });
                this.listView1.ItemsSource = people;
            }

        }
```

This will work..:)

Comment: ObservableCollection represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.                                        While setting ItemsSource property of some controls (e.g. datagrid or itemscollection) to every IEnumerable, there is no notification service applied.

But if we bind it to an ObservableCollection, any change in the list is recognized by the control...Tick it If you find it helpful..:)

Answer (score 0):

Just bind your listview to an ObservableCollection and it will automatically update the contents of the list.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
 ...
</ListView>
```

and in ViewModel (or code behind) declare the property Persons:

```
Public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
{
...
}
```

The trick is that ObservableCollection implements INotifyCollectionChanged, so it tracks when items are added or removed from the collection and updates the source.